# Unable to display response from the webservices call in codename one

Tags: java, codenameone

I am getting  this JSON response from my webservices 
`{root:[{name:abc, surname:xyz}]}` and I'm trying to display only the Key:Value from the response using label.

I am using the add component method

```
hi.addComponent(new Label(""+ response.get("/result[0]/ocassion")));
```

But it's showing me null value. I have followed videos on Webservices available in the codenameone website.

What should i try to get required response to be displayed on the UI.
Here is `MyApplication.java` code from codename one:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
response = parser.parse(reader);
System.out.println(""+ response);
hi.addComponent(new Label(""+ response.get("/result[0]/ocassion")));
hi.getComponentForm().revalidate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `parse.parse` to `parse.parseJSON`. You have to know the key to retrieve the value, you can loop through your response as follows:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
response = parser.parseJSON(reader);

List listResponses = (List) response.get("root");
if (listResponse != null) {
    for (Object listResponse : listResponses) {
        Map tempHash = (Map) listResponse;
        hi.addComponent(new Label("Name: " + tempHash.get("name").toString())); 
        hi.addComponent(new Label("Surname: " + tempHash.get("surname").toString())); 
        System.out.println(tempHash.get("name").toString()); //Print abc
        System.out.println(tempHash.get("surname").toString()); //Print xyz
    }
    hi.getComponentForm().revalidate();
} else {
    System.out.println("null value returned"); //Make sure you reference root and be sure it returns proper json
}
```

Comment: hi. thanks for that piece of code. it works as i wanted. but now i am doing some changes with the label and want to use multi buttons so that when the button is pressed it will show the name and the surname. can you suggest me how to do that.